# Symfony 3.4 Doctrine: Change referenced table on runtime

Tags: php, symfony

In my symfony application products are stored in the table `products`. There is an Entity `Product` and Repository `ProductRepository` for it.

Some products automatically get archived and stored in another table, called `products_archived`. I created an Entity `ProductArchived` and duplicated the ProductRepository file to the file ProductArchivedRepository.php.

*The tables products and products_archived have exactly the same structure and fields.*

My goal: 
When in the code a product is identified as an archived product, I want to be able to apply a function from the ProductRepository and NOT having to refer to a separate ProductArchivedRepository. I want to avoid having to use duplicated code.

Example:

**ProductRepository.php:**

```
public function getProductDataById($productId) 
{
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

   // ...

   return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

**ProductArchivedRepository.php:**

```
public function getProductDataById($productId) 
{
   $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

   // ...

   return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
}
```

**ProductService.php:**

```
public function getProductDataById($productId)
{
    $repoProduct = $this->productRepository;
    $repoProductArchived = $this->container->productArchivedRepository;
    if ($repoProduct->findOneBy(['id' => $productId]) instanceof Product) {
        $repoP = $repoProduct;
    } else if ($repoProductArchived->findOneBy(['id' => $productId]) instanceof ProductArchived) {
        $repoP = $repoProductArchived;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(
            'Product neither found in table product nor in table product_archived.'
        );
    }

    $productData = $repoP->getProductDataById($productId);

    return $productData;
}
```

How do I achieve that ProductArchivedRepository.php becomes redundant?

Comment: the very simplistic answer: add a field "archived" to your Product entity and just keep everything in one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an abstract class that regroup the duplicated method(s)

```
abstract class AbstractProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getProductDataById($productId) 
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');

        // ...

        return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
    }
}
```

And now, both of your repository can extend the abstract class instead of `EntityRepository` :

```
class ProductRepository extends AbstractProductRepository
{
    // ...
}

class ProductArchivedRepository extends AbstractProductRepository
{
    // ...
}
```